# Vim: How to gather all matching and surrounding lines from file?

Tags: regex, vim, editor

Since suggestion for a separate VimOverflow was rejected, would have to continue posting here.

I had to move translations from one file to another one only `msgid` matches some specific RegExp.

Translations are repeated in blocks, plus they can span multiple lines:

```
# English.po

#: ...
msgid "..."
msgstr "..."

#: templates/common/commonTranslation.phtml:10 | These parts can be
#: any/number/of/lines/can/precede/the/data:0  | of any length.
msgid "buttonhelp.edit"                       <- Matching string
msgstr "Edit your details"                     | 
"the long line continues"                      | Translation
"and can be even longer"                       |

#: ...
msgid "..."
msgstr "..."
```

Here is what I did in Sublime:

1. Did a regexp for `msgid` pattern that I need.
2. Sublime places multiple cursors around the file.
3. Up, Up, Shift-Down-Down-Down-Down – all translation blocks with the surrounding blank lines are selected.
4. Cmd-C, Paste in the new file. Done.

How could I do that in Vim?

Just to reiterate, I need multiple selections that I can extract to a separate file based on the `msgid` value. Here is what a single selection block looks like including the trailing and leading blank lines:

```
     
#: templates/common/commonTranslation.phtml:10
msgid "buttonhelp.edit" # <- value for regexp
msgstr "Edit your details"
```

**Update**
Sorry at first I didn't realise that my self, but translations can span an unspecified amount of lines, that's where Sublime fell short, since I have selected blocks of a fixed size. But translations are always separated by a blank line, except the end of file, but we can disregard that. This is the shortest amount of data possible:

```
     
#~ msgid "hotline.title"  | POEdit stores obsolete
#~ msgstr "HOTLINE"       | strings as well
```

**Solved**
Thanks to commenters it finally dawned on me and here is what I did in the end:

```
:let @a=''
:g/\v"\w+\.\w+"/norm! "Ayap
:tabe
:put A
```

It clears up the `a` register first, finds all lines with dots between words inside quotes (`"\w+\.\w+"`) and yanks the surrounding paragraphs into the `a` register the content of which I am pasting into a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to "yank" all those blocks in register `a` , you could try this in vim:

```
:g/msgid "buttonhelp\./norm! 2kV2)"Ay
```

in above `:g` cmd, the `msgid "buttonhelp\.` is the regex to match your msgid.

before exec the `:g` cmd, please do a `qaq` to clear the `a` register.

Comment: Thanks, this worked even better, provided it selected the whole paragraph since translation could span multiple lines, something I completely omitted in Sublime and now I would have to recheck everything :/ However the last translation was omitted completely, the file ends on `msgid` line without the corresponding translation. Guess that can be ammended by adding an empty line at the end.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make myself clean. In the new file that I got after pasting the buffer the last translation was missing. Not sure how that was possible, there is a blank line, so `)` should have worked. I will check it later.

Comment: I guess something like `"Ayap` at the end instead of `2kV2)` would do that even better, so it copies the whole translation block from the top blank line to the bottom one.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate (and execute a `yank` command) on all matching lines via `:global`.

In case you always need the lines above and below the `msgid` line, you can specify those as a *range* `.-1,.+1` (`.+2` to include the empty separator line, too).

To accumulate all matches in a register, first clear it, and use the uppercase for (for appending):

```
:let @a = '' | global/^msgid "\.\.\."/.-1,.+1yank A
```

To put that into another buffer, you can use

```
:new | put! a
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked. Is there a way to do search first and then just do `global` with specifying a regexp again?

Comment: Also is there a way to copy up to the end of paragraph in this case as translation could span multiple lines, something I was oblivious to unfortunately.

Comment: You can omit the regexp if you already searched for it: `:g//`. You can also do searches (to end of paragraph) with a range, see `:h :range`.